# Create BOM (bill-of-material) file on Windows

Tags: windows, macos, installation

I have to create (or rather modify) software package for MacOSX on Windows. I can do what I need with .pax files, so the only thing left is bill-of-material.

Does anyone know of a library that can do it? Is there BOM file format (Apple-version) available?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now an open source version of mkbom which also compiles for windows at:

http://hogliux.github.io/bomutils/

The windows version still contains some bugs (no special characters in file names and limitations on file path length). However, it should work for simple installers.

The website also has an easy to follow step-by-step tutorial on how to create a Mac OS X installer (however, the tutorial is for linux, see http://hogliux.github.io/bomutils/tutorial.html ).

Answer (score 1):

Well, BOM is not necessary, MacOSX package is a simple directory structure with optional elements, BOM being one of them.

Comment: This is not true when installing packages such as applications or kernel extensions.